# How exclude the export of subtable when you are already exported the root table via JSPDF using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, export-to-excel, jspdf-autotable

In the code bellow , i exported the table with tag #table1 using JSPDF and it works perfectly but i didn't find how i can exclude the export of the subtable  using AngularJs,

khnowing that, i fetch for a solution in the net but i just found  Jquery solutions and not whithin AngularJs
Any help please ,i apreciate it a lot  :)

perfectly using the code bellow

```
//************************Here is the code in the controller file 

        $scope.exportToExcel = function (tableId) {
            var exportHref = Excel.tableToExcel(tableId, 'report');
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = exportHref;
            a.download = 'Liste_Des_Transactions.xls';
            a.click();
 }

//*****************************Code in Html file
<button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="exportToExcel('#table1')">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> Export to Xls
</button>
            <table class="table table-hover " id="table1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>ID </br>Package</th>

                    <th data-translate="agroBourseApp.transaction.produit">Produit</th>
                    <th data-translate="agroBourseApp.transaction.variete">Variété</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="transaction in vm.commandEmited ">
                  <tr>             

                    <td>{{transaction.produit.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{transaction.variete.libelle}}</td>

                </tr>
                <tr has-any-authority="ROLE_RESP_FO,ROLE_TRD_AGB,ROLE_RESP_SLS,ROLE_RESP_DR,ROLE_RESP_DC,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_RESP_BO,ROLE_RESP_SUPP,ROLE_SUPPORT "
                    ng-show="dayDataCollapse[$index] ">
                    <td colspan="18 ">
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <table class="table table-hover " style="background-color:rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.842)">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>ID </br>PACKAGE</th>
                                            <th>ID </br>Deal</th>
                                            <th>Date </br>Transaction</th>                                        
                                            <th>Actions</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr data-ng-repeat="sub in vm.subs | orderBy: '-date_transaction' ">
                                            <td>
                                                <a ui-sref="trxdetails({id:sub.transaction.id})">{{sub.transaction.id}}</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a ui-sref="subtx({id:sub.id})">{{sub.id}}</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>{{sub.date_transaction | date:'short'}}</td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```